# Generate JWT in Google cloud function - python

Tags: python, rest, google-cloud-platform, jwt, google-cloud-functions

I wrote a script and uploaded it to GCFunctions. 
Now, one of my functions is using **PyJWT library** in order to generate JWT for GCP API calls,
the problem is that I keep getting errors every time I run the function.
When I added pyjwt to 'requirements.txt' I got the error: **'Algorithm RS256 could not be found',**
then I tried to add cryptography (the encrypting library that pyjwt uses), and also tried pycrypto (for RS256 registering) but still nothing.
I'd be grateful for some help here! even suggestions for other ways of authentication methods in GCP API calls would be great!
**Thanks in advance!!**

Edit: BTW- the function is running on Python3.7

Here is the content of my requirements.txt file (dependencies)

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
requests==2.21.0
pycrypto
pyjwt==1.7.1
pyjwt[crypto]
boto3==1.11.13
```

And this is the exception I get while trying to add **pyjwt[crypto]** and run the script once again:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVNXa.png)

Comment: If your goal is to authorize Google API calls you will need to use Access or Identity Tokens. Signed JWTs are accepted by only a few services. This means either user credentials or service accounts depending on the service. Some services support both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a way to make it work. Posting it here for those who will face it in the future...
I decided eventually to upload a zip file that contains the code file + requirements.txt + service account JSON Credentials file and added the following libraries as dependencies(to requirements.txt): oauth2client, google-api-python-client.

Here's how I did it:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
import logging

# set the service with the credentials
credentials = GoogleCredentials.from_stream("my_creds.json")
service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
# block errors printing for 'googleapicliet.discovery'
logging.getLogger('googleapicliet.discovery_cache').setLevel(logging.ERROR)

def main(event, context):
    # Project ID for this request.
    project = '<project_id>'  

    # The name of the zone for this request.
    zone = '<zone>'

    # Name of the instance resource to return.
    instance = '<instance-id>'

    request = service.instances().get(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance)
    response = request.execute()

    # print only network details of the instance
    print("'{}' Network Details: {}".format(response['name'], response['networkInterfaces'][0]['accessConfigs'][0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the [PyJWT installation documentation](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html), if you plan to do encoding or decoding of JWTs you should use the following pip install command to install it as a required extra along with `pyjwt`:

```
pip install pyjwt[crypto]
```

or add `pyjwt[crypto]` as a new line in your `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Throws me an exception -.- "Crypto Module cannot be found"

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `which pip`, `which python`, and `python --version`?

Answer (score 0):

As you want to use the GCP APIs I would recommend you to use the client libraries, as when using the client libraries the authentication is managed by the library itself, therfor there is no need of managing the security by yourself.

[here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) It is recommended by Google to avoid doing the authorization process explecitely. and instead using the propper client libraries.